# Using Win Server 2008 Group Policy to create printer and default colour

Tags: printer, windows-server-2008, group-policy

I have created a GPO to create a printer & default it from a shared printer on the server when logged in to domain. The shared printer on the server is configured to default colour: *Black & White*. However when the printer is created when someone logs into the domain, the default colour of the printer is: *Auto*.

How could I make sure its B&W, like the shared printer is?

Comment: Look at `rundll32 printui.dll, PrintUIEntry /?`, especially parameters `/Ss /Sr and /y`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you configure the printer properties on the server the usual way, you are just configuring it for users logged directly onto that server.

If you want a configuration to be the default used by all who connect to the shared printer, you need to setup the "*Printing Defaults*":

[image]

Once you click that button, it will open another dialog window similar to the regular settings, except that any settings you set in there will become the defaults used by the client(s).